# I don't find the build tools 16 can I use the 17?

Tags: java, android, osgi, android-sdk-1.6, embedded-osgi

I am relative new in Android world so if my question don't make sens please have patient with the new guy.

I what to dexifing some jars so I can run a OSGi environment on android. My problem is I can't download the build-tools revision 16 with the SDK manager because isn't there.

I tried direct download in this both links:

http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r16-windows.exe

http://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html

in the first it has a Manager than do not download the version 16 instead force me to download the version 22.x and the second does not have the build tools.

So: can I use the dx command of the build tools 17 if my phone has android 4.1 (API 16)?

If anyone is now wondering why I am not only trying. This is because there are several jar which I think wouldn't work straightforward then I want to avoid a problem source before starting and not knowing what is the problem I have to solve.

PS: I want to run OSGi for running a already developed software (middleware) so any help to make this possible even without dexifing would be helpful (if it is reasonable in complexity and time).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you wonder will it work on Api-16-driven device.

Look at the AndroidManifest.xml in your project

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

So, if `minSdkVersion` (minimal) is less or equals 16 - it will work fine

Comment: Which manifest? I am converting jars into APK for that I have to dexifing them. There is no Android project therefore no android manifest til a finish the conversion which needs the command `dx`from `build-tools` which come in every SDK release. So do you still think there is no problem?

Comment: every APK is a packaged Android project. Every APK should have a manifest file. android:minSdkVersion is the parameter that sets minimal device version. You should look at that. But most likely it is less than 16

Comment: Until I not able to test it works I can't say it is the right answered. Anyhow either I don't get what you mean or you don't get what I mean. Look at http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-and-google-android.html and tell me which manifest?

Comment: You guys are not talking about the same manifest (both Android and OSGi have the concept of a manifest, but they are two different things).